# Is there a difference in meaning between 匹敵 and 互角?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

Is there a difference in meaning between 匹敵 and 互角?

Besides that one is a suru verb and the other a noun/adjective

Answer (score 2):

When you say AとBは互角だ, A and B are treated equally. AとBは互角だ and BとAは互角だ are semantically the same sentence. In addition, 互角 is used only in the context of competition; the speaker is always interested in which is the stronger/superior one.

On the other hand, AはBに匹敵する means A is comparable or competitive with B. The focus of this sentence is on A, and B's strength/value is taken for granted. Thus, AはBに匹敵する and BはAに匹敵する are not the same. Besides, 匹敵 has a broader usage outside the context of competition. For example, [デジタル大辞泉 lists](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8C%B9%E6%95%B5/) 演歌に匹敵する外国の音楽 "foreign music (genre) comparable to *enka*" as an example of 匹敵する. This means that *enka* and something are similar, but it doesn't mean the speaker wants to decide which genre is superior.